# Where should I place named pipe files on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, mkfifo

I done some quicky web searches to find out how to make a named pipe.  It looks very straight forward I just need to execute as root: `mkfifo filename`, but what the best practice on where on the filesystem to put named pipes? Should they go into `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/var/lib` or somewhere else?  Also should I follow any naming convention or is there names I should avoid?

Thanks!